# Adding a message or a next line just after completing a task in gradle

Tags: java, ant, groovy, gradle, task

I have a project with **subprojects projA and projB**.

How can I add a new line just after **executing any task from root project** ?
What I tried is:

I wrote a task to print next line in commonClosures.gradle file and included it in module gradle files (apply from:). The issue I am facing is, the task runs multiple times when running from root project.

**Directory structure:**

```
testPro/
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
│   ├── commonClosures.gradle
│   └── wrapper..
├── gradlew
├── projA
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── gradle
│   │   └── wrapper..
│   ├── gradlew
│   └── settings.gradle
├── projB
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── gradle
│   │   └── wrapper..
│   ├── gradlew
└── settings.gradle
```

**cat settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'testPro'
include 'projA','projB'
```

**cat build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply from: 'gradle/commonClosures.gradle'
```

**cat projA/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply from: '../gradle/commonClosures.gradle'
```

**cat projB/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply from: '../gradle/commonClosures.gradle'
```

**cat gradle/commonClosures.gradle**

```
gradle.taskGraph.afterTask { 
    println "task completed"
}
```

Output:

```
~/workspace/ROOT_PROJECT

]$ ./gradlew clean
projA
:clean UP-TO-DATE
task completed
task completed
task completed
:projA:clean UP-TO-DATE
task completed
task completed
task completed
:projB:clean UP-TO-DATE
task completed
task completed
task completed

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

is there any simple way to handle this ?

Comment: Are you running the task at all?

Answer (score 0):

As in the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/execution/TaskExecutionGraph.html#afterTask(groovy.lang.Closure)) `afterTask` will be executed after every task that was added to the graph. It can be done with action:

```
project.tasks.clean.doLast {
    println '\n'
}
```

What are you trying to achieve?

It works well:

```
gradle.taskGraph.afterTask {
   println "lol" 
}

task lol
```

> [opal@opal-mac]/tmp % gradle lol
>   :lol UP-TO-DATE 
>   lol
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL
>
> Total time: 2.866 secs

**EDIT**

It's quite easy to explain. Since you apply `commonClosures` to all `build.gradle` scripts it's in fact applied three times. So the closure is executed three times. Such closure should be applied only to `rootProject`'s `build.gradle`. Have a look [here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/30480280).

Comment: Oh I am sorry to confuse. I mean for all tasks. Not only for clean task. It should give a next line for all tasks.

Comment: Yea it works when i do it from 'inside' a subproject. I want this when-ever i run a task from rootProject

Comment: @smilyface, could you please provide a SSCCE that reproduces the problem? It might be located on GH e.g.

Comment: SSCCE added. Please check.

Comment: Thank you for the update. It works only when i am running task from root project. When trying to run from inside module (say projA) it does not prints the message.

Comment: Sorry for not replying for so long. It seems that you need to detect if `commonClosure` was applied and if not apply it. Unfortunately I don't know how to check. It's possible to check if a plugin was applied.

Comment: Hmm.. I too came up with the same solution. If I am finding any, surely i ll inform here. I tried with setting a boolean globally (false if not applied true if applied) but unfortunately i culdn't make it work.